# slide-toggle should not change when I click the `confirm cancel` button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, materialize, slidetoggle

In my project I used slide-toggle to activate or deactivate a product.
Everything works ok, only when I add a confirmation dialog, my slide change  like in [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bspml8-qtafs2?file=app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.html).

So when I click cancel, slide-toggle change when I click ok, slide-toggle changes.

My code html:

```
<mat-card class="result">
  <mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>
     <section class="example-section">
      <mat-slide-toggle
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          [checked]="checked"
          [disabled]="disabled"
          (click)="myfunction()">
        Slide me!
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </section>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

code ts:

```
export class SlideToggleConfigurableExample {
  color = 'accent';
  checked = false;
  disabled = false;
    myfunction() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to change Status?')) {
     }
  }
}
```

That I want to say is, how to change my slide-toggle when I click ok, when I click cancel, I do not want to change anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle
      class="example-margin"
      [color]="color"
      [checked]="checked"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (click)="myfunction()"
      onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    Slide me!
  </mat-slide-toggle>
```

and remove  `if (confirm('Are you sure to change Status?')) {}` from ts

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bspml8-qtafs2?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-configurable-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: #c8e38f;
}
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: #91c71f;
}
.mat-slide-toggle .mat-ripple-element{
    background-color: rgba(145, 199, 31, .12);
}
```

this is all style for color mat-slide-toggle

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks